# Is there a ruby gem that enables cross-platform mouse manipulation?

Tags: ruby, automation

I need the ability to programmatically trigger a mouse click at specific coordinates. I've found AutoIt and the auto_click gem which both supposedly provide this ability, but only on Windows. I've also found the rautomation gem which aims to provide cross-platform capabilities, but which doesn't seem to support anything other than Windows at the moment.

Are there any other gems out there that allow automating mouse clicks at specific x/y coordinates directly from Ruby?

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://github.com/Quintus/Automations/

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a heavily system-dependent task. You should provide your code a way to load system-dependent gems (AutoIt on Win, Automations on Linux). If you are targeting Mac OS, you could build your own lib by calling `CGPostMouseEvent` from the `CGRemoteOperation.h` via the FFI library.

For example:

require 'ffi'

```
module Mouse
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib '/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics'

  class CGPoint < FFI::Struct
    layout :x, :double, :y, :double 
  end

  attach_function :CGPostMouseEvent, [ CGPoint, :bool, :int, :bool ], :void
end

point = Mouse::CGPoint.new
point[:x] = 100
point[:y] = 100

Mouse::CGPostMouseEvent(point, true, 1, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [rumouse](https://rubygems.org/gems/rumouse) gem. It provides simple API and supports linux, osx and windows.