# Capture Mouse Events in the Terminal using Ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal, command-line-interface, mouse, ansi-escape

Here's some code I've been experimenting with:

```rb
print "\e[?1003h"

begin
  loop do
    begin
      input = ARGF.read_nonblock(1024)
      puts "input: #{input.inspect}"
    rescue IO::EAGAINWaitReadable
    end
  end
ensure
  print "\e[?1003l"
end
```

When I run this code, I can see content like this being printed to the terminal, but none of it indicates it's being sent to `ARGF`. I've tried `STDIN` as well. My `read_nonblock` calls always raise `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable`, which seems to be the expected behavior (see [spec](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1721bb9dc6dcc3ecec05e9d6f72654099460ef50/spec/ruby/core/argf/read_nonblock_spec.rb#L65)).

```
^[[MCn@^[[MCn?^[[MCn>^[[MCm>^[[MCm=^[[MCk;^[[MCk:^[[MCj:^[[MCi:^[[MCh:^[[MCg:^[[MCe:^[[MCd:^[[MCc:^[[MCb;^[[MCb<^[[MCc<^[[MCd<^[[MCe<^[[MCf<^[[MCg<^[[MCg;^[[MCf;^[[MCf:^[[MCe:^[[MCd:^[[MCd;^[[MCd<^[[MCe<^[[MCf<^[[MCg<^[[MCg;^[[MCg<^[[MCg;^[[MCf;^[[MCf:^[[MCe:^[[MCd:^[[MCd;^[[MCe;^[[MCe<^[[MCe;^[[MCf;^[[MCe;^[[MCe:^[[MCe;^[[MCf;^[[MCe;^[[MCd;^[[MCd<^[[MCe<^[[MCe=^[[MCf=^[[MCf<^[[MCe<^[[MCe;^[[MCd;^[[MCc;^[[MCc<^[[MCd<^[[MCe<^[[MCe;^[[MCe<^[[MCf<^[[MCf;^[[MCe;^[[MCd;^[[MCd<^[[MCe<^[[MCe=^[[MCf=^[[MCg=^[[MCh=^[[MCi>^[[MCj>^[[MCk>^[[MCl>^[[MCn?^[[MCpA^[[MCqB^[[MCrC^[[MCrD^[[MCsD^[[MCsE^[[MCtF^[[MCsG^[[MCrG^[[MCqG^[[MCpG^[[MCpH^[[MCmH^[[MCmG^[[MClG^[[MCgI^[[MCfI^[[MCeI^[[MC]I^[[MC\I^[[MC[I
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a ruby gem that enables cross-platform mouse manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558315/is-there-a-ruby-gem-that-enables-cross-platform-mouse-manipulation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do your own processing, you have to capture the characters in [`raw`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/IO.html#method-i-raw) mode.

This should work: (I've tried to keep your code structure)

```rb
require 'io/console'

at_exit { print "\e[?1003l" }

print "\e[?1003h"

STDIN.raw(intr: true) do # raw mode but allow ctrl-c
  loop do
    begin
      input = STDIN.read_nonblock(1024)
      p input: input
    rescue IO::EAGAINWaitReadable
      IO.select([STDIN])
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

Output: (while moving the mouse)

```
$ ruby mouse.rb
{:input=>"\e[MCYB"}
{:input=>"\e[MCZB"}
{:input=>"\e[MC[B"}
{:input=>"\e[MC\\A"}
{:input=>"\e[MC]A"}
{:input=>"\e[MC]B"}
{:input=>"\e[MC\\B"}
```

Of course, you still have to actually process that mouse input in a meaningful way.

Comment: I tried this and it worked exactly as expected.

A follow up question: I noticed STDIN is still printed. Is there a way to silence it?

Comment: @Scoobie `raw` should already disable echoing. Maybe you print it yourself?

Comment: My code only prints a data-type I created (similar to yours printing a Hash). It's a small problem, I've dealt with it by using `print "\x1b[1K\r"`